# Indexing and DataType of TenantId Linked to suser_sid() in a Multi-tenancy database

Tags: sql, sql-server, multi-tenant

As is a common approach for Multi-Tenancy Databases, I have a TenantId in every table, which in turn is the same as suser_sid, and views based on he tables which filter by TenantId=suser_sid().

While this works fine for most part, since my suser_sid() returns a datatype varbinary(85), the natural datatype to have for TenantId is varbinary(85).

This for obvious reasons doesn't make it ideal to be included in the Primary Key or Foreign Key relationships, as I believe having a variable length in your primary indexes is a bad idea(let me know if I am wrong).

Would using binary(85) for the TenantId be a better idea? or shall I go with bigint, and just do convert like so Convert(bigint, suser_sid()) and do a comparison with that, and hope for no collissions for different tenants.

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatically, the `guid` is a good candidate for the tenant identifier and it very much supports indexing and can be used as primary key in self and as a foreign key in the referencing tables. If you have to generate one from the code too not a big logic or thought process is called for. Just calling `Guid.NewGuid()` will do the trick in C#. SQL server also can return the last inserted I'd at ease. Hence I feel that it might be the right candidate.

Comment: Wouldnt the 16 byte GUID be overkill for a 85 bit binary identifier. Would it provide better indexing performance than say binary(85) ?

Comment: I have not tried so as of now don't have results to share. But how about generating the unique values when using binary as a column data type. From the application point of view guid has an equivalent type and it is not the case with binary. If some efforts go into ensuring the uniqueness of the binary value and outweighs the guide we can considering using.